# What's the best way to take a picture and display the result using Kotlin Anko?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I'm playing around with Anko for Kotlin and was trying to use it to take a picture and then display the resulting image in my test application using the below android training document as a starting point.

http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

What would be the best way to implement this functionality using Anko?

I'm trying to use the startActivityForResult function, but I'm not having any luck figuring out how to add an image view to the layout that I can update with the result from onActivityResult.

Comment: It is good if you showed some sample code with what you attempted, and what specific things worked or did not.  Otherwise the question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

I will paste you a bit of my code, I use Picasso to render the images to an imageview from an Url which is a good practice because it will handle everything optimally for you:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val imageReturned = 100

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        //With when we select the request code we asked in the StartActivityForResult
        when(requestCode){
            //that will be imageReturned
            imageReturned -> Picasso.with(this@LoginActivity)
                .load(data?.getStringExtra("theUrl")).into(image_view)
            //now what we did here was use Picasso to load 
            //the URL in the StringExtra "theUrl" into image_view, 
            //image_view will be the synthetic bound of anko for it to 
            //work you have to `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_login.*`
        }
    }
}
```

This is if you binded your views from the XML if you havent, and used anko DSL to achieve it then you must get the contentView with findViewById(android.R.id.content) and then search for your Imageview by id then set it the same as I did up there.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have done Android development in Java before, it really doesn't differ much from Java other than syntax.

The tutorial is enough. Try to follow that and convert the Java file to Kotlin using Android Studio Kotlin Plugin. You will learn and figure it out by yourself how to map Java code to Kotlin and vice versa.

1. [Install Kotlin plugin for Android Studio](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/08/working-with-kotlin-in-android-studio/) if you have not already
2. Open the Java file
3. Click `Help > Find Action` menu to open Find Action
4. Search for "Convert Java file to Kotlin file"

---

Regarding your question about setting the image in `onActivityResult` (with respect to the tutorial you mentioned). You can use the `Uri` defined in `dispatchTakePictureIntent()` to set in `ImageView`.